# After deploying SharePoint extension locally, It is not displaying context menu for Document Library folders and Documents

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I have created an SharePoint Extension for Context menu on Folders and Documents. It is working fine as expectation in debug mode but after deploying it(tried locally only), I am not able to see Context Menu for neither Folders nor documents.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Title="LeafletForSharePoint"
        RegistrationId="100"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.ContextMenu"
        ClientSideComponentId="5cac5dbb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cf11039cxxx"
        ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;leafletNew&quot;:&quot;LeafletNew.&quot;, &quot;leafletEdit&quot;:&quot;LeafletEdit.&quot;,&quot;leafletCustomization&quot;:&quot;LeafletCustomization&quot;}">
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

I have uploaded .sppkg file and added it to Site Content.

Comment: Do you have a feature associated with your extension? If you do - you might need to activate this feature on the target site.

Comment: Yes. I have feature and also I have activated it

Comment: What do you mean by deploying it(tried locally only)? Are you referring to SP2019 on-premise or SPO?

Comment: I am referring to SPO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by using RegistrationId="101"

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction
    Title="LeafletForSharePoint"
    RegistrationId="101"
    RegistrationType="List"
    Location="ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.ContextMenu"
    ClientSideComponentId="5cac5dbb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cf11039cxxx"
    ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;leafletNew&quot;:&quot;LeafletNew.&quot;, &quot;leafletEdit&quot;:&quot;LeafletEdit.&quot;,&quot;leafletCustomization&quot;:&quot;LeafletCustomization&quot;}">
</CustomAction>
```